# jQuery trigger an event while form is posting

Tags: jquery, forms, events

Was just wondering if there is a simple way to trigger an event (such as displaying a loading spinner) once the form action is started (form starts posting) until the action is done (then the spinner disappear). Something like displaying spinner when ajaxStart and hiding it when ajaxStop posting.

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to do if the form is posted via ajax:

```
$("#throbber").show();
$("form").ajaxSubmit().done(function () {
   $("#throbber").hide();
});
```

Just put the throbber `<img>` in a sensible place in the html and set it to `display: none` initially.

Comment: no the problem is the form is not posted via ajax! any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean regular HTML form submission, then yes, you can intercept the submission with a `form.onsubmit = function(){...}` handler.

Return `false` to inhibit submission, or `true` (or anything other than `false`), to allow it.

In jQuery :

```
$("#myForm").on('submit', function(){
    ...
    return true;//or false
});
```

However, depending on how fast the server responds, the spinner may never show or only for a very brief moment, before the page is renewed.

Comment: Thanks it triggers the event (shows my loading spinner when I submit) but I need to have another handler to hide the spinner when the submit is finished (action is done). any idea?

Comment: I don't understand. With regular HTML form submission, the page will be renewed or replaced. After submission, it's too late to do anything on the page from which the form was submitted.

Comment: correction, I guess the form does not get submitted, I press a button and a report is ready to be downloaded without refreshing the page. its just the button action that does the job. Im using Java and jsp coding

Comment: Then whatever utility orchestrates the form submission must be doing AJAX.